# How do I stop Visual Studio resizing the side panels when unpinned/pinned?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

My standard VS2010 setup has the Solution Explorer docked on the left-hand side, with a few other panels (Class View, Team Explorer, etc.) tabbed behind it:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 with Solution Explorer docked]

However, if I click the pin icon to collapse that panel (to give me more space to work on my code), then later click the pin again to re-dock it, it always appears much thinner: see the second screenshot below.

**Solution Explorer panel collapsed...**
[image]

**And now re-docked. Gah! Thin!**
[image]

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to remember my preferred width for that panel? I'm forever re-sizing it and it drives me nuts. I've tried closing/restarting VS with the panel docked in the hope that it would persist but every time I hide/restore it it goes back to the thinner width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this very same problem which is still present in VS2013 Update 4, and found the solution.

This problem only happens when the pinned tool is grouped with other tools.

For me it was "Properties" and "Find and Replace" that were grouped together on the right. I could not make them retain their size while they are unpinned/pinned until I ungroup the tools.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, that works! Bit of a rubbish implementation from Microsoft but great to know there's a reliable workaround. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Perspectives add-in](http://perspectives.codeplex.com)? This should allow you to save and restore window layouts and may help you with this.

Comment: No, unfortunately that hasn't fixed it. I'm still getting exactly the same problem after installing Perspectives and saving a default perspective.

Comment: (It does look handy for other reasons though - just not this one.)